# Can personnel who manage AWS datacenters access my ec2 instances and monitor data in use in my application?

Tags: amazon, datacenter

I am building an Express (NodeJS) app and plan to host with AWS ec2. I want to protect my users' data as much as possible and am considering even outlier scenarios. And so the question arose:

The ec2 instances are physical managed in some Amazon datacenter and there are obviously personnel who manage those facilities who have physical access to those machines. Can they theoretically access the applications residing on those servers and view/monitor/steal sensitive data that is currently in use in the application?

Should this even be a concern? If so, what can we do as developers to mitigate this?

Comment: Can they? Yes. What can stop them? Privacy regulations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they can theoretically access or monitor the data.

No, this should not be a concern.  Their incentives (organizationally and individually) to provide a stable, secure service are certainly greater than their incentives to steal your application's data, out of all of the millions of virtual machines and applications that they manage the infrastructure for.

As a developer, there is very little you can do to mitigate this, outside of not hosting with Amazon.  Or any other cloud or managed service provider.  Or collocation facility, for that matter.

Ultimately, any infrastructure that is out of your control is, well, out of your control.  This should not keep you up at night though.  It's like spending your time worrying about being abducted by aliens.  While the risk is theoretically possible, you would get more value for your time by focusing on just about any of the more mundane and realistic risks that your application will actually be in danger of falling prey to, like any of the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10).

**Steps you *can* (and should) take**:

So, are there steps that you as an application developer can take to protect your data despite these realities?   Sure, there are several things you can do.

The most basic (and possibly obvious) is don't collect or keep any data you don't absolutely need, and purge the data you do keep as soon as you can.  Less data means less to lose in an attack.

Second, protect the data your application uses.  Start by protecting it in transit.  Use HTTPS/TLS for communications between your application and the users.  This is an effective and inexpensive way to protect it from anyone who has access to the data center network to sniff traffic on the wire.  Protect it at rest as well.  If you have user passwords, protect them with a slow hash algorithm like  bcrypt.  This way, even if the data is accesses, it can't be easily abused.  For other sensitive data you can look at encryption, and major cloud providers these days (Including Amazon AWS and Microsoft Azure) offer cloud-based HSMs for protecting encryption keys.  While still not foolproof, it at least guarantees that someone who gains access to your VMs or disk images won't also capture your encryption keys.

To sum up, there are always steps that you can take that will make your application and data more secure, even when you don't control the infrastructure.  It still boils down to understanding your application and business needs, the realities of how and where it runs, and then threat modeling it correctly for its purpose and environment and mitigating appropriately. From there, following standard secure design, development, and operational practices will help to ensure that your application and data are as safe as they can be.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although "very little" can you recommend some methods a developer COULD use to mitigate this? Encrypt "data in use"?

Comment: @ryd3r Certainly, I've updated the answer with several steps you can take.

Comment: A good list until we get inexpensive homomorphic encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It’s good to come up with a list of things you don’t want them to do (“take my data” is too vague), and apply mitigations from there.

How would they do that? Could they:

- Access your AWS Portal instance? Enable enhanced security so that no one from AWS can access it without your permission.
- Login into your EC2? Only if you haven’t secured it with credentials, and have wide open internet access.
- Steal the physical disks? Well, infra engineers wouldn’t know what disks to take, and they are encrypted. Though, the key is selected by AWS by default. You’d enhance this with your own keys, which are managed in the portal.
- Monitor traffic? Encrypt everything with TLS 1.2 or higher
- Copy your EBS volumes? Encrypt them.
- Log into your data stores? Encrypt them, secure them with creds, and use network rules to minimise access through limited endpoints.
- Read your source code for secrets? Store them in a vault manager and retrieve them at runtime.
- Read your secrets? Configure them so only authorised hosts can access them.

Same goes for you as well though:

- Are you AWS CLI credentials protected from unauthorised access?
- Are they cycled on a regular basis?
- Is there f/w rules to limit who can access you AWS instances?
- Can you move to PaaS services so you eliminate all IaaS risks altogether?
- Are you using a separate environment for dev/test/prod with complete network segregation between instances?
- Are you proactively monitoring logs for misuse and taking action on suspicious activities.
- Have you applied all the recommendations from the AWS security products?

AFAIK AWS offer no system maintenance or technical support of IaaS services, other than technical faults (e.g. network outages, unexpected power failures etc). You’d need to engage with a third party specialist. Their access would be substantially higher than AWS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).